# problems while implementing tiny language parser in python

Tags: python, parsing

i was hoping if someone could help me in the implementation of tiny language parser. i was trying to implement the grammar of the tiny language (attached photo)[image: grammar of tiny language], but i have some problem with some functions; which are simple_exp, exp, factor, term. these function i have implemented some code in it based on the grammar but it keeps outputting[image: output errors] errors. here is the code of the parser, i have put it in a list so i could control elements inside it

```
import scanner3


def program(l):
    if len(l) > 1:
        if l[len(l) - 1].value is ";":
            print("ERROR.. semi colon at last line")
            return False

        return stmt_seq(l)

    else:
        print("minimum num of expressions is not met")
        return False


def stmt_seq(l):
    if stmt(l):
        if l[0].value is ";":
            l.remove(l[0])
            return stmt(l)
    else:
        print("hiiio")
        return False


def stmt(l):
    if if_stmt(l):
        print("hi1")
        return True
    elif repeat_stmt(l):
        print("hi2")
        return True
    elif assign_stmt(l):
        print("hi3")
        return True
    elif read_stmt(l):
        print("hi4")
        return True
    elif write_stmt(l):
        print("hi5")
        return True
    else:
        return False


def if_stmt(l):
    if l[0].value == "IF":
        l.remove(l[0])
        exp(l)
        if l[0].value == "THEN":
            l.remove(l[0])
            stmt_seq(l)
            if l[0].value is "END":
                l.remove(l[0])
                return True
            elif l[0].value is "ELSE":
                l.remove(l[0])
                stmt_seq(l)
                if l[0].value is "END":
                    l.remove(l[0])
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False


def repeat_stmt(l):
    if l[0].value is not "REPEAT":
        return False
    else:
        l.remove(l[0])
        return True


def assign_stmt(l):
    if l[0].type == 'var' and len(l) > 1:
        if l[1].value == ":=":
            l.remove(l[0])
            l.remove(l[1])
            # return exp(l)
            return True

        return False


def read_stmt(l):
    if l[0].value == 'READ' and len(l) > 1:
        if l[1].type is "var":
            l.remove(l[0])
            l.remove(l[1])
            return True
        else:
            print("ERROR is in read in line " + str(l[0].line_no))
            return False

    else:
        return False


def write_stmt(l):
    if l[0].value == "WRITE":
        l.remove(l[0])
        # return exp(l)
        return True
    return False


def exp(l):
    # for wa7da in list(tokens.queue):
    #     print(wa7da.value, ", ", wa7da.type, "  in line ", wa7da.line_no)
    # print("________")
    if simple_exp(l):
        if comparison_op(l)and simple_exp(l):
            return True
    return False


def comparison_op(l):
    print("compaaaaare "+l[0].value)
    if l[0].value is "<" or l[0].value is ">" or l[0].value is "=":
        l.remove(l[0])
        return True
    else:
        print("ERROR is in comparison in line " + str(l[0].line_no))
        return False


def simple_exp(l):
    if l[0].value is "+" or l[0].value is "-":
        return term(1)
        return True
    else:
        return False

    # return term(l)
    # if term(l):
    #     if add_op(l):
    #         return term(l)
    #     return True
    # else:
    #     return False


def add_op(l):
    if l[0].value is "+" or l[0].value is "-":
        l.remove(l[0])
        return True
    else:
        print("ERROR is in add in line "+str(l[0].line_no))
        return False


def term(l):
    if l[0].value is "*" or l[0].value is "/":
        mul_op(1)
        return True
    return factor(l)
    # if factor(l):
    #     if mul_op(l):
    #         return factor(l)
    #     return True
    # else:
    #     return False


def mul_op(l):
    if l[0].value is "*" or l[0].value is "/":
        l.remove(l[0])
        return True
    else:
        print("ERROR is in mul in line "+str(l[0].line_no))
        return False


def factor(l):
    print(l[0].value)
    if l[0].value == "(":
        l.remove(l[0])
        exp(l)
        if l[0].value == ")":
            l.remove(l[0])
            return True

    elif l[0].type == "num":
        l.remove(l[0])
        return True
    elif l[0].type == "var":
        l.remove(l[0])
        return True
    else:
        print("ERROr is in factor in line "+str(l[0].line_no))
        return False


# #####main
tokens = scanner3.tagheez("res.txt").tokenz
for wa7da in tokens:
    print(wa7da.value, ", ", wa7da.type, "  in line ", wa7da.line_no)

print(program(tokens))
```

Comment: Have you stepped through your program with a debugger to ensure that the name `l` always has the type you think it has? It apparently turns into an integer at some point. By the way, `l` is a poor name, since it is easily confused with the number `1`. Also, what is in module `scanner3`? Your code is not complete without it. You should show us the full traceback, not a picture of part of it. Read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please give us text in text, not in screenshots and photos.

Comment: I think the suggestion by @RoryDaulton about `l` vs. `1` isn't just a good idea, but the whole crux of your problem. Doing a quick search for `1`, I see `return term(1)`, but `term` is clearly supposed to take a list of token objects, not a number, and… that could cause exactly the traceback you see here.

Comment: @abarnert i don't have the grammar in text unfortentually ,as for the other screen shot it's just displays the output error, i could change it right now

Comment: The fact that the scanner doesn't produce errors isn't enough; you need to know that it produces the right output (which appears to be a list of token objects that have `value` attributes that are strings).

Comment: It would take you 10 minutes, tops, to type in the grammar.

Comment: You don't seem to assign any value to the list `l` anywhere in your code.

Comment: As a side note: don't do `l.remove(l[0])`, just `del l[0]`. And definitely don't do `l.remove[l[0]]` then `l.remove[l[1]]`, because after the first `remove`, what used to be `l[1]` has moved up to `l[0]` and you're removing the wrong thing; use `del l[:2]` to remove the first two elements.

Comment: i think their might be a misunderstanding term takes in it's input the letter l which is a list, not number 1 @abarnert

Comment: @MariamMohieSleem Look at your code: inside `simple_exp`, it clearly does `return term(1)`, not `return term(l)`. And that typo is the cause of your whole problem. And using the name `l` is why you didn't notice the typo.

Comment: @abarnert i would do that replace the remove with the deletr

Comment: Also, that same function, immediately after doing `return term(1)`, does `return True`. You realize that `return True` can never happen, right?

Comment: yes i saw that but still when i tried to enter the tiny code in an incorrect format it still didn't caught the error

Comment: could you please explain what you mean ? @abarnert

Comment: I don't know how to explain your typo in more detail in a comment, so I wrote an answer. But really, it's just a simple typo that you should be able to find and fix easily.

Comment: yes thank you i saw the comment but if you please answer the question that i asked on your answer it would be so helpful @abarnert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have multiple places in your code where you're passing the number `1` instead of the list of tokens `l`. For example:

```
def simple_exp(l):
    if l[0].value is "+" or l[0].value is "-":
        return term(1)
```

… and:

```
def term(l):
    if l[0].value is "*" or l[0].value is "/":
        mul_op(1)
```

All of your functions expect to get a list of tokens as `l`, not a number. The first time one of them tries to do `l[0].value` or similar when `l` is the number `1`, it will raise exactly the exception you're asking about:

```
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I don't know which of these typos is the one causing your specific problem, but it doesn't matter; you obviously need to fix all of them.

And, as Rory Daulton suggested in the first comment, this is exactly why `l` is a terrible variable name. If your variable were called `tokens` or `lst` or almost anything else, you could immediately tell that `1` was a mistake, but because it's `l`, which looks almost identical to `1`, you can't see the problem even after it's been pointed out to you.

Of course you also have other bugs in your code (e.g., `l.remove(l[0])` followed by `l.remove(l[1])` will remove the first and third elements, not the first two, and, at a deeper level, your `term` isn't checking for a term at all, it's just checking for a `mul_op`), but this is the one that's blocking you.

Comment: thank  you for your answer and i have already changed the typos, but another problem appeared, i have output in the stmt_seq function that "hiiio" as s sort of telling me where the error might be , when i run the program the output is "hiiio" after it is false, if you could help me in it it would be extremely nice as i suspect there is an error in the logic of these funcs (simple_seq,factor,term)

Comment: @MariamMohieSleem As I already suggested, there are at least three more obvious bugs in this code, and there may well be more than that. You cannot use a StackOverflow question to iteratively debug all of the bugs in a program like this. If you’ve gotten farther and run into another problem and tried to debug it but gotten stuck, you should have a specific problem that you can ask as a new question. But you can’t expect us to do all the debugging for you.

Comment: @MariamMohieSleem If you do need step-by-step handholding, a site like PythonTutor, or the IRC channel listed in the Community section at Python.org, or some other chat-based site might be more helpful than a Q&A site like Stack Overflow.